Equatable doesn't work in bloc event and always triggered with same value
I implemented equatable in bloc event to prevent if the data that i push is same or not with before.
push event
BlocProvider.of<FeedbackBloc>(context) 
      .add(SubmitFeedbackEvent(userFeedback: 'Hallo!'));

from event file
sealed class FeedbackEvent extends Equatable {
  const FeedbackEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

final class SubmitFeedbackEvent extends FeedbackEvent {
  const SubmitFeedbackEvent({required this.userFeedback});

  final String userFeedback;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [userFeedback];
}

from bloc file
class FeedbackBloc extends Bloc<FeedbackEvent, FeedbackState> {
  FeedbackBloc() : super() {
    on<SubmitFeedbackEvent>((event, emit) async {

      final userFeedback = event.userFeedback;

      print(userFeedback);

    });
  }
}

But when i check the event, it still trigger every time i push with same value userFeedback
when i click button 5 times to push event:
expectation
Output:
Hallo!
reality
Output:
Hallo!
Hallo!
Hallo!
Hallo!
Hallo!

You should provide a complete demo, as well as the expected and actual execution results.

it happened too in here link question, you can see at there if the code provided too

It can happen from bloc, please consider including minimal-reproducible-example

I don't understand what both of you need, so i follow what all of you want. now can  both of you answer my problem?. i already attach my code
